# Wordpress bootstrap not responding properly on the phone

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i installed a bootstrap theme and tried to match my bootstrap site to the blog
checkout [jamaicainn.com][1]

the problem is when i am resizing the browser to see how it looks on mobile, the theme works. But it doesn't work properly on the actual mobile phone.

Comment: do you have any examples of your html?

Comment: pls check http://jamaicainn.com/index.php for the codes

Comment: I think you have included your footer twice, and that'll slow down the loading of the page. And i see that the navigation bar doesn't close up after clicking on it the second time, you should check the js codes. And I suggest that you go to [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) ,and take the scripts from there, so they'll be updated and well written.